# Title case for a paragraph

Tags: python, string, python-2.7, for-loop

I'm creating a markov chain algorithm. I output a variable called sentences which contains one string of sentences. I want to make the sentences sentence case so I wrote this:

```
for l in range(0, len(sentence)-1):
    if l == 0:
        sentence[l].upper()
    elif sentence[l] == ".":
        sentence[l+2].upper()
```

What this does is, capitalizes the first letter of first word. Then if it encounters a period, two characters after it is the beginning of a new sentence. However, I don't know how to mutate the sentence. This is what I've tried, but is illegal:

```
elif sentence[l] == "."
    sentence[l+2] = sentence[l+2].upper()
```

And no, sentences.title() will not work because it will make every word title case.

Comment: What you are describing is not *title case*. Title case means every word is capitalised. What you are describing is just correct capitalisation for sentences. It's also worth noting that iterating by index is a really bad way to do anything in Python. Iterate over values, the language is designed for that - it's faster, easier, reads better, and is more flexible.

Comment: @Lattyware Whoops, I meant sentence case. Fixing now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Python already has a `.capitalize()` method:

```
>>> 'this is a sentence.'.capitalize()
'This is a sentence.'
```

The problem is, it won't work for multiple sentences:

```
>>> 'this is a sentence. this is another.'.capitalize()
'This is a sentence. this is another.'
```

Nor does it handle whitespace well:

```
>>> ' test'.capitalize()
' test'
>>> 'test'.capitalize()
'Test'
```

To get around that, you can split the sentences up, strip the whitespace, capitalize them, and then join them back together:

```
>>> '. '.join([s.strip().capitalize() for s in 'this is a sentence. this is another.'.split('.')]).strip()
'This is a sentence. This is another.'
```

You could also do it with regex, which should be a little more versatile:

```
import re

def capitalizer(match):
    return match.group(0).upper()

sentence = 'this is a sentence. isn\'t it a nice sentence? i think it is'
print re.sub(r'(?:^\s*|[.?]\s+)(\w)', capitalizer, sentence)
```

And the output:

```
This is a sentence. Isn't it a nice sentence? I think it is
```

Comment: Note that `str.strip()` will strip *all* whitespace, so this could cause some loss of extra whitespace between sentences - it's unlikely to be a problem, but worth noting.

Comment: The regex is indeed versatile. is there a way to split ! and ? liek the regex, with pure python? The only way I can think of doing it is copying the code and replacing '.', but that seems silly.

Comment: @PhilKurtis: Just change your code to say `elif sentence[l] in ".!?":` and it'll work.

Answer (score 1):

Strings are *immutable*, in Python. You can assign the new string again to tha same variable, or convert it into list, mutate the list, and `''.join()` it again.

```
>>> sentence = list("hello. who are you?")
>>> for l in range(0, len(sentence)-1):
...     if l == 0:
...         sentence[l] = sentence[l].upper()
...     elif sentence[l] == ".":
...         sentence[l+2] = sentence[l+2].upper()
...
>>> ''.join(sentence)
'Hello. Who are you?'
```